How to pass constexpr to constructor?
I have a template A with non-type parameter:
template <int param = 0>
class A
{
public:
    static constexpr void print()
    {
        std::cout << param << std::endl;
    }
};

And I have a class B, in the constructor of which I'm going to use the template A.
class B
{
public:    
    B()
    {
        A<> a{};
    }
};

To initialise a I want to use constexpr int from main function.
int main()
{
    constexpr int val = 123;

    B b{};
}

In case of general function, I could just turn it into the template, but as far as I know it does not work for constructors. At least it didn't work for me.
Making the entire class B into a template is not an option, I need it to remain a class.
Is it possible to pass val from main to class B constructor?

You must expose a constexpr constructor for B that passes its param into A

cout isnt const expression

Oh, really. I'll fix it.

I know that cout is not a const expression, it is just used for an example.

The problem is that you need to pass the consexpr variable from main which is only possible using templates(not counting macro). So making B should be the obvious choice which you said isn't possible.

Given the constraints, I believe the answer is "no".

@Evg I realise that in the case from the example if I leave A<> this will be converted to A<0>.  In my example the template is left without parameters because I wanted the example to be compilable. Also, a is not a member of a class and I don't need it to be.

@user12002570 In the actual project, class B is large, so turning it into a template would be a problem.

You might use std::integral_constant to pass that constant:
class B
{
public:
    template <int N>
    explicit B(std::integral_constant<int, N>)
    {
        A<N> a{};
    }
};

int main()
{
    constexpr int val = 123;

    B b{std::integral_constant<int, val>{}};
}

Demo

It worked! Thank a lot.
